# Submit Search query & get Search result without refresh

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I want to **submit search query** form & get **search result** without **redirecting/reloading/refreshing** on the **same page**.

My content is dynamic so can not use those "submit contact form without refreshing page which replies back on success".

Comment: Search should be done **using** refresh. You have to learn basic standards.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel, Today I see that users hate clicking the page, waiting for content to load, etc... so, no refresh solutions do can handy ;)

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel, You don't know me or know my work, so that aggression is unnecessary! On the other hand, I made reference to users and not me, and I did so knowingly because of all the projects that I'm involved! (I did think on the first and on this one)

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel, besides, you're expressing your personal opinion based on google staff decisions ?!? And I really believe that the user is the "boss" and if the user doesn't want the page to refresh, the page must not refresh!! Do you Agree!??

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel, Jesus... you're really cranky! Never mind that... it's a question of opinions, not standards... (btw: refresh was enforced, not chosen)

Comment: a bit late as a response but Google doesn't refresh anymore when searching

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In order to submit a form, collect the results from the database and present them to the user without a page refresh, redirect or reloading, you need to:

1. Use Ajax to Post the data from your form to a php file;
2. That file in background will query the database and obtain the results for the data that he as received;
3. With the query result, you will need to inject it inside an html element in your page that is ready to present the results to the user;
4. At last, you need to set some controlling stuff to let styles and document workflow run smoothly.

---

#### So, having said that, here's an working example:

We have a table "persons" with a field "age" and a field "name" and we are going to search for persons with an age of 32. Next we will present their names and age inside a `div` with a `table` with pink background and a very large text.
To properly test this, we will have an header, body and footer with gray colors!

**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

<html lang="pt" dir="ltr">

  <head>

    <title>Search And Show Without Refresh</title>

    <meta HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css">

    <!-- JQUERY FROM GOOGLE API -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function() {
        $("#lets_search").bind('submit',function() {
          var value = $('#str').val();
           $.post('db_query.php',{value:value}, function(data){
             $("#search_results").html(data);
           });
           return false;
        });
      });
    </script>

  </head>

  <body style="margin:0;padding:0px;width:100%;height:100%;background-color:#FFFFFF;">

    <div style="width:1024px;margin:0 auto;height:100px;background-color:#f0f0f0;text-align:center;">
      HEADER
    </div>
    <div style="width:1024px;margin:0 auto;height:568px;background-color:#f0f0f0;text-align:center;">
      <form id="lets_search" action="" style="width:400px;margin:0 auto;text-align:left;">
        Search:<input type="text" name="str" id="str">
        <input type="submit" value="send" name="send" id="send">
      </form>
      <div id="search_results"></div>
    </div>
    <div style="width:1024px;margin:0 auto;height:100px;background-color:#f0f0f0;text-align:center;">
      FOOTER
    </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

**db_query.php**

```
<?php

define("HOST", "localhost");

// Database user
define("DBUSER", "username");

// Database password
define("PASS", "password");

// Database name
define("DB", "database_name");

// Database Error - User Message
define("DB_MSG_ERROR", 'Could not connect!<br />Please contact the site\'s administrator.');

############## Make the mysql connection ###########

$conn = mysql_connect(HOST, DBUSER, PASS) or die(DB_MSG_ERROR);

$db = mysql_select_db(DB) or die(DB_MSG_ERROR);


$query = mysql_query("
  SELECT * 
  FROM persons 
  WHERE age='".$_POST['value']."'
");

echo '<table>';

while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {

  echo '
  <tr style="background-color:pink;">
    <td style="font-size:18px;">'.$data["name"].'</td>
    <td style="font-size:18px;">'.$data["age"].'</td>
  </tr>';

}

echo '</table>';

?>
```

The controlling stuff depends from what you want, but use that code, place those two files in the same directory, and you should be fine!

Any problems or a more explicative code, please let us know ;)

Comment: Thanks Zuul for your descriptive answer. It really helped me to understand AJAX role.

Answer (score 1):

This is what AJAX is for.
In jQuery (apologies if you're looking for a different library)

```
$("form#search").bind('submit',function() {
  $.post("search.php",this.serialize(),function(data) { 
    // Put the code to deal with the response data here
  });
  return false;
});
```

Comment: Well I am newbie, I dont even know basics. so can you elaborate on more?

Comment: since you are binding on submit, its a good idea to return false to prevent it from submitting anyways.

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably want to start with any of the thousands of "AJAX for beginners" tutorials you can find on the net.  A Google search with that term should get you going.

Try this for starters:

http://www.destraynor.com/serendipity/index.php?/archives/29-AJAX-for-the-beginner.html

After you've read through that, keep in mind that you really don't need to be writing any XHR handling code.  As pointed out by Jamie, jQuery or any of the other multitudes of Javascript libraries out there, can greatly simplify your client-side AJAX code.

Comment: Thanx desau for the suggestion

Comment: @desau, your link is broken.

Answer (score 1):

It's good if you can get some basics of Ajax before straight away going to the code. 
Ajax , is the exact solution for your problem. It asynchronously makes a request to the server, get the result and the data in the page can be modified with the result . It's all done in JavaScript.

Suppose you have an html like this:

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="myDiv"> your content area</div>
<button type="button" onclick="loadByAjax()">Change Content</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Now, your javascipr code will be like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadByAjax()
{
     $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "yourserverpage.php",
          data: "searchkey=data_from_user_input",
          success: function(response_data){
          $('myDiv').html(response_data)
          }
          });
}
</script>
```

so, basically upon click of the button, the JavaScript will be executed. It wil call the php serverside script, pass the parameters it got from user input and retrieve the response data and place it inside the div.
So your page is updated without full refresh.

Also, please understand that, i used jquery library here for the Ajax function.