# How to search dynamically in mysql database from php form

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, html

I've a table on php form with `search|---------|`textfield connected to mysql database.
What I want- If I entered some of text in search textfield it will show me records that contain this text automatically and when I click on that it will be selected.
e.g-In patient table

```
name='Vilas Galave',
name='Ashok Galave'
```

And I entered 
    search |Galave| it will show

```
'Vilas Galave'

'Ashok Galave'
```

Comment: Use select query with "Like % %" .

Comment: If you need it without refreshing the page try this--
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4182548/search-query-get-search-result-without-refresh-pagenation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should checkout the [string comparison functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html) in mysql. For example you could use a query like this to display all rows that contains the text `Ashok`:

```
SELECT * FROM <table> WHERE name LIKE '%Ashok%'
```