# Ajax with multiple submit buttons

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jquery

How can I change the code below so instead of a text input type with a submit button I want multiple submit buttons each with their own unique value? Everything I try just ends up with submit's value being undefined. Any help would be great!

Code source: [Submit Search query & get Search result without refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3074380/submit-search-query-get-search-result-without-refresh)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#lets_search").bind('submit',function() {
            var value = $('#str').val();
            $.post('db_query.php',{value:value}, function(data){
                $("#search_results").html(data);
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>

<form id="lets_search" action="" >
    Search:<input type="text" name="str" id="str">
    <input type="submit" value="send" name="send" id="send">
</form>
```

Comment: try $('#send').click(function(){ // code here }); and insted of type=" submit" take it as type="button"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add multiple submit buttons and attach to all of them `onclick` event listener. When button was clicked - get the value and send with a POST request.

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $('input[type=submit]').click(function(){
        $.post('db_query.php', {value:$(this).val()}, function(data){
            $("#search_results").html(data);
        });
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
<form id="lets_search" action="">
    <input type="submit" name="button1" value="hi"/>
    <input type="submit" name="button2" value="bye"/>
</form>
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for with the least amount of extra typing, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use multiple submit buttons, you can catch the click event and determine which button was clicked. then run different Ajax submit. this also works when `enter` is hit.

```
//submit buttons
<form id="lets_search" action="" >
    Search:<input type="text" name="str" id="str" />
    <input type="submit" value="v1"/>
    <input type="submit" value="v2"/>
    //...more submit buttons
</form>    

//submit func
$(function() {
    $("#lets_search input[type=submit]").click(function() {
         switch  ($(this).val){
             case 'v1':...;
             case 'v2':...
         }
    });
});
```

Comment: why e.target? $(this).val() should be enough as already pointed out by sanjeev

Comment: Actually I think your solution will work better since you are binding the button click instead of the form submit

Comment: thanks man, :),,,I wasn't thinking about the syntax, but only for demo. I update it anyway.

Comment: This is nice, however, why not use `id` instead?  Cause using `val` will cause the submit button to say: `v1` and `v2` which doesn't make any sense to the end-user.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my version - which now looks very much like Bingjies because it was written while I was testing out his version

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/XA53C/show)

```
<form id="lets_search" action="" >
Search:<input type="text" name="q" id="q">
<input type="submit" value="Google" name="send" id="google">
<input type="submit" value="Bing" name="send" id="bing">
</form>

$(function() {
  $("#lets_search input[type=submit]").click(function() {
    switch  ($(this).val()) {
        case "Bing" :
            $("#lets_search").attr("action","http://www.bing.com/search");
            break;

        case "Google":
            $("#lets_search").attr("action","https://www.google.com/search");
            break;
    }        
  });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can have multiple submit buttons in the form, no problem. They may have the same name, type  etc, but just assign them different values. Like Submit Button 1 can have value="hi" and Button 2 can have value="bye".

Then when the action function is called for the button, all you have to do when entering the function is do a check with: $(this).val

```
HTML:

<input type="submit" name="button1" value="hi"/>
<input type="submit" name="button2" value="bye"/>

jQuery:
$(function() {
    $("#lets_search").bind('submit',function() {
        var value = $(this).val();

        if(value == "hi")
            do_something;
        else
            do_something_else;
    });
});
```

Comment: Will the val be returned on the form submit? I think you need to bind click instead

Answer (score -1):

Here, I would prefer to Vamsi's solution n Why not Sanjeev mk?

Give some extra thought on prefering the solution.

**case: If there are mulitple submit buttons**

If the user is in the text field and hits enter, the system will assume the first submit button was hit.

> So, here, it would be good to go for not having mulitple submit
>   buttons for end user point of view

Comment: Please provide expln along wih -ve vote, else it would be of waste

Comment: I did not vote down, but I suggest you convert this to a comment like "Please note that in case of multiple submit buttons:

If the user is in the text field and hits enter, the system will assume the first submit button was hit." since your answer comes across as a bit rambling and not as an answer

Comment: ok.iam answering here by casestudying the answers. Not always only answers are answers.

Comment: In this case you will only get downvoted - so that is your own choice