# How to show query search results without reloading on button click in laravel

Tags: laravel

I am trying to show query results without reloading in laravel
[image]

This is the form in which I get the category and country

```
<form class="new_is" id="lets_search" action="{{route('advanced-search.show','searchInfluencer')}} method="GET">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <label>Category</label>
                 <select name="filter_category" id="filter_category" class="influencer-category-picker form-control form-select" >
                    <option value="">Click to select the category</option>
                    @foreach($Categories as $Category)
                        <option id="category" name="{{$Category->id}}" value="{{$Category->id}}">{{$Category->name}}</option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6">
                <label>Location</label>
                   <select name="filter_country" id="filter_country" class="influencer-category-picker form-control form-select">
                    <option value="" >Click to select the Country</option>
                    @foreach($Countries as $Country)
                        <option id="country" value="{{$Country->id}}">{{$Country->name}}</option>
                    @endforeach
                    </select>
            </div>
            <div id="advanced-search" class="col-md-12" style="margin-top: 20px">
            <p>
                <button type="button" name="filter" id="filter" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary track-event">Search</button>
            </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

This is the controller including the query and returning the result and everything works well but on another page

```
public function searchInfluencer(Request $request)
{
    $category = $request->get('category');
    $country = $request->get('country');
    
     if(empty($category) && !empty($country)){
        $influencers =Influencer::where('country_id', $country)->get();
        return response()->json($influencers);
     }
     elseif (!empty($category) && empty($country)){
        $influencers =Influencer::where('category_id', $category)->get();
        return response()->json($influencers);

    }
    elseif (!empty($category) && !empty($country)){
        $influencers =Influencer::where('category_id', $category)->where('country_id', $country)->get();
        return response()->json($influencers);

    }
```

Here is the index function:

```
public function index(){
    return view('businesses.advanced-search-business', [
        'Genders' => Gender::all(),
        'Countries' => Country::all(),
        'Categories' => Category::all(),
    ]);
}
```

The issue is that on clicking the search button, I want to show the results on the same page without reloading. Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Go through and you will find your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3074380/submit-search-query-get-search-result-without-refresh

Comment: Thank you so much it worked well, but is there any way to return the data and do the loop with the html in the view not in the .php file? thank you in advance @WhoDoYouthinkami

Comment: you can implement JS for that. for example Write some text directly to the HTML output:

document.write("Hello World!");