# update search results and url on submit without refreshing -larevel

Tags: laravel

I am trying to retrieve a list of plants from a database. To do this the user must enter a name in a search bar. I would like that when the results are displayed the page is not reloaded entirely but only the part that contains the search results.

I have tried a solution with ajax that works, I get the plant list by checking the console.log(), but the problem is that the url doesn't change, so if the user saves this url to come back to the same search results later it will fall back to the main page.

I was also interested in a solution with Blade, so that when the form is submitted, it returns the same view with only the @yield changing (which contains the results) without refreshing the "parent" page.

So I'm on these two different tracks to solve my problem, which one is the best to take? and how would you do it?

Comment: take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3074380/submit-search-query-get-search-result-without-refresh and https://www.nicesnippets.com/blog/laravel-9-refresh-datatable-without-reloading-page btw both use AJAX

Comment: Have you thought about using Livewire, does what you need out of the box.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.